# How can I give the same look to all my different UITableViews through my application?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

This should be a pretty basic question, I'll be happy even if you can link to some sort of article/tutorial that covers this (or a similar) subject.

I have an application with four tabs, each tab containing a navigation controller with a table view. I am **not** using `UITableViewController` subclasses, as I want to have a static view on top of some tables and an image background below everything. I am also using different types of custom cells (mostly configured with images and code in `-willDisplayCell`). As I want the same look and feel for all my tables, I am wondering how could I reuse some code, but I'm having trouble to figure this out. Do I have to create a "base" `UIViewController` subclass with a `UITableView` outlet, and then use this one as my superclass? Or do I have to just implement my `UITableViewDelegate` in a separate class and use an object of that class as the table view delegate? Or should I use a custom `UITableView` and subclass that one instead?

I could give more details if needed, but I suppose this is enough for a starting discussion. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would consider subclassing UITableView and setting the `dataSource` and `delegate` to self and implement GUI logic inside the class and create a custom logic for getting your data in and out (probably forwarding some dataSource/control delegate functions to one of your VCs).

The layouting code for cells should really be placed inside cell logic! You should consider creating custom `UITableViewCell` subclasses (and maybe XIBs for them) that contain logic for layouting & reusing. (Maybe a `dataObject` property that makes the cell read your model?!). You can then use your UITableView subclass to create and manage those cells (e.g. a mapping between model classes and XIB names)

This is probably a way to generate a lot of reusable code where you just need to change details like adding model classes or modifying their layouting, or subclassing model classes or subclassed UITableViewCells.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this is to make a custom view which inherits UITableView. override initWith `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style` and set the GUI that you want to use in table.

Now you can use this class in your application wherever you want.

Now as you are using different cell patterns Will suggest you make one class for each cell and inside you cellForRowAtIndexPath make object of different cell based on some flag or data structure. Read Factory Design Pattern to understand this concept in deep.

Basic flow will be like this.

1. Alloc a new custom table.
2. Assign datasource and delegate to same table class OR to class which holds the table.
3. Load data in table.
   -> Here while loading data figure out what kind data is being used. Based on data make object of relative cell.

This will make all cell and Table reusable throughout application.

For further details read about Decorator Design Pattern.

Post if need for details.

Comment: So, if I subclass UITableView, how can I implement the UITableViewDelegate protocol?

Comment: @interface MyCustomTable : UITableView<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

Comment: @interface MyCustomTable : UITableView<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> -> Please note this code demonstrates how can you implement any Delegate in your code when you make views without XIB. Do not get confused that you have to necessarily implement UITableViewDelegate in the class which inherits UITableView. It can be implemented in any class. Assign reference of class that implements UITableViewDelegate in delegate property if UITableView subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would indeed say the best thing would be to inherit your `UITabBarController`s from a `MasterController`.

Inside this `MasterController` `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillLoad` do you can write common layout and setup that will be used later on by your subclasses.

This is also much more convenient because you can in your `MasterController` implement methods to refresh your views accordingly.

It could also be nice to have one basic NIB file loaded trough this `MasterController` and for which custom layout could be done in the children controllers (for example in the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method.

I think creating a subclass of `UITableView` is not a good idea because you are not customizing the behavior of Table View per se but you are customizing the controller that uses it instead.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: The NIB way 
If you decide to go with the NIB file you can still go with one MasterController by proceeding as followed.

1. In your MasterController create the necessary outlets (here I think
   you only need the TableView but it can be more complexe)
2. In InterfaceBuilder setup your connections as you would normally do
3. In your code when you create the `UITabViewController`s you will use
   the `[[YourTabBarController alloc]
   initWithNibName:@"YourMasterNIBFile.xib" bundle:nil]`

Because the outlets will be inherited, your class `YourTabBarController` which will inherit `YourTabBarController`, will have all the necessary information to correctly build your view.

I hope this is clear enough, I've used this method for one of my applications and time consumed to build that `MasterController` was definitely worth the pain for all the flexibility it provides.

Comment: I agree that I should subclass UIViewController. But in this case, can I use nib files for my subclasses? Do I have to declare the UITableView of the superclass as an outlet, or I'm getting it really wrong?

Comment: nope Irene I think your are getting it right but simply messing up with what needs to be subclassed. I've edited my answer to explain a bit more about the outlets and your nib files.

Answer (score 0):

I do this by creating one base class (either uiviewcontroller or uitableviewcontroller), and having a new init method with Type. For example, if you are creating this in code (non-nib)

- (id)initWithType:(NSInteger)tabtype;

Make this base class also your delegate/datasource, and implement all required methods.
Depending on which tab the viewcontroller was instantiated for, adjust the datasource methods - setup different data to show.  Delegate methods are probably still same across your view controllers so nothing changes there.

I normally do UI stuff in code, so you could do static view using viewcontroller with a tableView subview, or you could also put static view on top of UITableView, by adding it to tableView as subview, then override layoutSubviews to adjust the y coordinate to make it look like it is static on one spot.  (WWDC2011 session Advanced Scrollview Techniques shows how to do this).

If you are using NIB though, then you have to use initWithNib, then easiest way to do this is subclass the baseclass again into 4 different cases for each of your tab.

Now since your code is factored into baseclass, if you want to make change, then it's only one class to change.

Answer (score -2):

Out of interest, why would you want to have a static view on top of tableview cells?

You can have a background image behind the tableview cells with UITableViewController.

Comment: because I don't want the top-most view to scroll together with the table view. And I think you should have added a comment instead..

Comment: I don't think your explanation given here is adequate to explain what I think is probably a flawed idea from a user experience perspective.

Comment: Your input is really appreciated, but I'm already aware of the impact of my decision to the "user experience". Thanks anyway.

Comment: go to your contacts app and look at the A-Z bar at the right.. that's a static view above a table view. those are useful for user experience